# Using the verb 'Supply' in a sentence

Tags: sentence-structure, verb-usage

Do the following sentences in each pair mean the same?

> - These foods **supply** the body **with** necessary vitamins and minerals.
> - These foods **supply** necessary vitamins and minerals **to** the body.

---

> - They are **supplying** Lebanon **with** arms.
> - They are **supplying** arms **to** Lebanon.

Comment: Yes, they mean the same.

Comment: Thanks @Jim. What about the sentences: ( - "These foods supply necessary vitamins and minerals of the body. ) AND ( - "They are supplying arms of Lebanon." ) Do these sentences mean the same like their relevant pairs above?

Comment: Those sentences don't really make any sense.

Comment: @Jim Why don't the sentences make sense? They seem fine to me, if vague.

Comment: @Catija= I suppose they make sense in a completely different context.  I.e., we are now talking about the noun phrases "vitamins and minerals of the body" and "arms of Lebanon" whereas before "the body" and "Lebanon" were indirect objects.   I was thinking A-friend wanted to replace *to* with *of* and retain the same meaning.

Comment: @Jim Sorry, I didn't realize the added sentences in the comments were different. You're right, they don't make much sense.

Comment: @A-friend particularly with the case of "*They are supplying arms **of** Lebanon*", you're implying that the arms already belong to Lebanon, which is confusing... because if they have arms already, why would they be being supplied by another group.

Comment: It was really helpful posts of you. But what about the forst pair of sentences @Catija?

Comment: @A-friend The sentences in your question are fine. All four of them. The two in your comment are problematic. I +1'd Jim's first comment, which is why I didn't say anything.

Answer (score 1):

The verb supply (amongst other verbs) takes two arguments, one which you might call the medium, and the other which you might call the recipient. With some verbs, the direct and indirect objects are fixed in their roles. However, with *supply* they can alternate.

The forms:

> - Supply something to someone
> - Supply someone with something

are semantically equivalent, although there one could argue that they emphasise different things.

Answer (score 1):

### Both are correct, they are called ***Direct & Indirect Objects***.

> These foods supply the body with necessary vitamins and minerals.

*"the body"* is the **indirect object** and *"necessary vitamins and minerals"* is the **direct object**.

> These foods supply necessary vitamins and minerals to the body.

*"necessary vitamins and minerals"* is the **direct object** and *"the body"* is the **indirect object**.

> They are supplying Lebanon with arms.

*"Lebanon"* is the **indirect object** and *"arms"* is the **direct object**.

> They are supplying arms to Lebanon.

*"arms"* is the **direct object** and *"Lebanon"* is the **indirect object**.

**indirect object** = object will receive action by direct object

**direct object** = object that will give action to the indirect object

*Please read here for more information » http://www.myenglishpages.com/site_php_files/grammar-lesson-direct-indirect-object.php*